# Assure my website visitors, that their data is safe from me, that I don't see their data

Tags: software-development, security, privacy

I am building a White Label website where I would like to allow my visitors to host their sensitive data.
At the same time, I would like to assure them that no one, including me, doesn't use or even sees their data.
I thought of encrypting the data, use a 3rd party to store the sensitive data, store it on their own servers.. but none of these seem to be the right solution.
How can I do that?

I looked at casino websites and tried to think what they are doing. White label casinos let their visitors insert their personal details. How can the White Label owners (the ones who bought and operate the Casino) be sure that the White Label providers (the ones who built the Casino) don't still these details?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Providers of white label casinos probably either can see everything, and use a third-party platform for all payments. If your goal is to host visitors data while still not being able to see it, then end-to-end encryption is probably the only solution.

Comment: This might be impossible given modern Web. If all they see is a website, you could try to implement all encryption client-side so that the key is stored in the client's browser and your server only sees encrypted data, but it would still be trivial for you to attack that by serving the user a modified script that uploads their keys to you and doesn't tell the user. The users need an independent audit of the client-side encryption code and some assurance that you haven't altered it since the audit.